# add a tag to each div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the current code:

```
  <div class="main-wrap">
    <div class="inner-wrap">
        some content here
        <span>
           <a href="1">test1</a>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="inner-wrap">
      some content here
      <span>
        <a href="2">test2</a>
      </span>
    </div>

    <div class="inner-wrap">
      some content here
      <span>
         <a href="3">test3</a>
     </span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I need to fetch the `href attr` of `a tag` within `span tag` and insert it to the whole `inner-wrap` element. Something like this:

```
  <div class="main-wrap">
    <div class="inner-wrap">
      <a href="1">
        some content here
        <span>
           <a href="1">test1</a>
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="inner-wrap">
     <a href="2">
      some content here
      <span>
        <a href="2">test2</a>
      </span>
     </a>
    </div>

    <div class="inner-wrap">
     <a href="3">
      some content here
      <span>
         <a href="3">test3</a>
     </span>
    </div>
   </a>
 </div>
```

I can fetch the href tag of each `a tag` but I'm confuse as to how to append it to the each `inner-wrap` divs. This is what I've done by far:

```
$('.inner-wrap').each(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $fetchLink = $this.children('span').find('a').attr('href');
    console.log($fetchLink);
});
```

I know this is really very simple but I can't get to work around. Can someone please help?

here's working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pv2cfr0g/)

Comment: Why would you want nested anchors in the result?

Comment: i think its wrong code.. an anchor tag inside anchor tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/), However, You should **not** nest anchor inside another anchor element.

```js
$('.inner-wrap').wrapInner(function(i) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var a = $this.children('span').find('a');
  var href = a.attr('href');

  //Remove inner anchor
  a.replaceWith(a.text());

  return "<a href='" + href + "'></a>";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrap">
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    some content here
    <span>
           <a href="1">test1</a>
        </span>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap">
    some content here
    <span>
        <a href="2">test2</a>
      </span>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap">
    some content here
    <span>
         <a href="3">test3</a>
     </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to work very well because you can't have a link within a link, but the general idea is to replace the `$.html()` of `.inner-wrap` with it's `$.html()` wrapped in an `a` tag with `$fetchLink` as the `href` attribute.

```js
$('.inner-wrap').each(function() {
  $this = $(this);
  $fetchLink = $this.children('span').find('a').attr('href');
  $this.html('<a href="'+$fetchLink+'">'+$this.html()+'</a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrap">
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    some content here
    <span>
           <a href="1">test1</a>
        </span>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap">
    some content here
    <span>
        <a href="2">test2</a>
      </span>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap">
    some content here
    <span>
         <a href="3">test3</a>
     </span>
  </div>
</div>
```